# Friend overstayed for a week in Schengen. Possible consequences for future visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying

My friend from Canada loves Europe. Recently when exiting they couldn’t find an entry stamp in her passport. On entry, She had gone through the immigration in the same line as I did (Schengen citizen) as it said Canada could go through. And it was electronic, so no entry stamp in the passport. But they fussed about this on exiting, but it turns out she would have overstayed by a week with that entry date. She had counted wrongly.

Anyway, the officer ended up saying not yo worry about it. So now I’m unsure if this will affect future travels to Schengen and also visas in the future in the Schengen zone.

She’s had a work visa before, but that was before all of this traveling.

Is this electronically recorded, or is this what the future Entry/exit thing will register, that is not in effect yet?

Comment: In Schengen, when you pass through automatic passport control, you have a little booth where you get your stamps verified for the 90-in-180 rule and your passport stamped

Comment: Yeah, but that didn’t seem to have happened in this case. She didn’t get an entry stamp when she went through the line that included Canadian residents

Comment: Since Canada is a low-risk country, the consequences are likely to be minor, if any. I'd suggest waiting at least a year with the next visit to the Schengen Area just to be safe. Getting a work visa in the future will also be possible.